# pass any one value and get that child tree or parent tree

Tags: sql, cursor, recursive-query, with-statement

i have one table and i want result as per picture result1 and result2[image]

Comment: i try this but not working 

select DevicePortConKey,SourceDevicePortKeyValue,DestinationDevicePortKeyno from
(select DevicePortConKey,SourceDevicePortKey,DestinationDevicePortKey from DevicePortConnections 
where SourceDevicePortKey=11 or DestinationDevicePortKey=11
) final
unpivot
(DestinationDevicePortKeyno for SourceDevicePortKeyValue in (SourceDevicePortKey,DestinationDevicePortKey) ) as value

Comment: ;WITH PortConnectionCTE_Front AS
( 
SELECT DevicePortConKey,SourceDeviceKey,DestinationDeviceKey,SourceDevicePortKey,DestinationDevicePortKey,ConStatus
FROM DevicePortConnections
WHERE SourceDevicePortKey in(11) or DestinationDevicePortKey = 11
UNION ALL
SELECT a.DevicePortConKey,a.SourceDeviceKey,a.DestinationDeviceKey,a.SourceDevicePortKey,a.DestinationDevicePortKey,a.ConStatus
FROM DevicePortConnections a 
INNER JOIN PortConnectionCTE_Front s ON a.SourceDevicePortKey = s.DestinationDevicePortKey
) 
SELECT *   FROM PortConnectionCTE_Front`

Comment: You should edit your post with your comments. It's easier to read.

Comment: Which RDBMS you are using?